# Determine the integers $x$ and $y$, knowing that it verifies the relation: $x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3=2023$

Tags: integers

Determine the integers $x$ and $y$, knowing that it verifies the relation:

$$x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3=2023$$

**My idea**

We can write the given relation as

$$(x^2+y^2)(x-y)=2023=7\cdot 17^2$$

I wonder if we can solve this problem in a different way than the method of testing for each possible option.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: What contest is this from?  And when does it end?

Comment: @YahavBoneh I edited the question. It was a misspelling. SORRY!

Comment: @B.Goddard My teacher told us to try to solve this question.

Comment: Each possible option? $7$ can't be a sum of two squares, neither can $7\cdot17$ or $7\cdot17^2$. $17$ can, but then $x-y$ is just not big enough. So the only option is...

Comment: I'm not sure; but can we use $(a-b)^3=6069$? Then we'll have $\frac{1}{3}a^3-a^2b+ab^2-\frac{1}{3}b^3=2023$, which is then equal to $x^3-x^2y+xy^2-y^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

- Each of $7, 7 \cdot 17, 7 \cdot 17^2$ is equivalent to $3$ modulo $4$ and so cannot be a sum of $2$ squares.
- The Triangle Inequality gives $x - y \leq |x| + |y| \leq x^2 + y^2$.

These two restrictions leave a single possibility: $$x^2 + y^2 = 17^2, \qquad x - y = 7 .$$ N.b. there are two solutions $(x, y)$.

Comment: What does N.b. stand for?

Comment: @EtackSxchange https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

Comment: @TravisWillse it tells no where that those numbers are the sidrs of a traingle.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Example_norms

Comment: @IonelaBuciu Even without knowing the triangle inequality you can see that $x^2+y^2=17^2$ is a Pythagorean triplet. Even if you aren't able to find $x$ & $y$ using this you can find $y$ from $x-y=7$ and substitute it into $x^2+y^2=289$ to find the integers.

Comment: Of course, one can separately check the three possibilities that are not eliminated by the first observations, but o.p. seemed to want to minimize the amount of checking individual cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can eliminate most of the options. I will write the possible pairs of values as $(a,b)$ with $x-y=a$ and $x^2+y^2=b$. With all possible values we have 6 options
$$ (7, 17^2), (17^2, 7), (17, 7 \times 17), (7 \times 17, 17), (1, 2023), (2023, 1) $$

Now consider solving the equations generically. We first have from the first equation
$$ x = y+a $$
Substituting into the second equation yields
$$ (y+a)^2+y^2 = b $$
$$ 2y^2+2ay+(a^2-b)=0 $$
We know this will have solutions if the discriminant is greater than $0$, so we must have
$$ (2a)^2-4(2)(a^2-b) \geq 0 $$
$$ a^2-2a^2+2b \geq 0 $$
which gives us
$$ 2b \geq a^2$$

(Alternatively you can consider the equations in a geometric context and consider the closest point to the origin on the line to arrive at a similar result)

With this result we can eliminate 4 options leaving only $(7, 17^2), (1, 2023)$ as possible options. Then just solve each pair as simultaneous equations (note only one of the two gives integer solutions). Travis Willse answer provides a more efficient method but this is just another way of going about it.